# PHP site URL ID please Help!

Tags: php, sql, url

Please could someone help im building my first website that pulls info from a MySQL table, so far ive successfully managed to connect to the database and pull the information i need.

my website is set up to display a single record from the table, which it is doing however i need some way of changing the URL for each record, so i can link pages to specific records. i have seen on websites like facebook everyones profile ends with a unique number. e.g. http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=793636552

Id like to base my ID on the primary key on my table e.g. location_id

ive included my php code so far,

```
<?php
require "connect.php";
$query =  "select * from location limit 1";
$result = @mysql_query($query, $connection) 
or die ("Unable to perform query<br>$query");
?>

<?php
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>

<?php echo $row['image'] ?>

<?php
}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Guys,Thanks for your comments, sorry i only started PHP yesterday, my knowledge is very very basic, is any one to able to rewrite the code above to include the statement that will assign the records Id number to the url, ive had a try but but im getting errors flag up and im kinda lost now thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $_GET to retrieve things from the script's query (aka command line, in a way):

```
<?php

$id = (intval)$_GET['id'];  // force this query parameter to be treated as an integer

$query = "SELECT * FROM location WHERE id={$id};";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
   echo 'nothing found';
} else {
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   echo $row['image'];
}
```

Comment: Craig, this will work fine, and since Marc is using `(intval)`, it is secure.  However, for just about anything else, you should be escaping your data.  Keep that in mind, so you don't run into serious SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things to consider if this is your first foray into MsSQL development.

**SQL Injection**

Someone might INSERT / DELETE, etc things via using your id from your url (be careful!, clean your input)

**Leaking data**

Someone might request id = 1234924 and you expected id = 12134 (so some sensitive data could be shown, etc;).

**Use a light framework**

If you haven't looked before, I would suggest something like a framework ([CodeIgniter](http://CodeIgniter.com), or CakePHP), mysql calls, connections, validations are all boilerplate code (always have to do them).  Best to save time and get into making your app rather than re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have selected the record from the database, you can redirect the user to a different url using the `header()` function.  Example:

`header('Location: http://yoursite.com/page.php?id=123');`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a link to the same (or a new page) with the URL as you desire, and then logic to check for the parameter to pull a certain image...

if you're listing all of them, you could:

```
echo "<a href=samepage.php?id=" . $row['location_id'] . ">" . $row['name'] . "</a>"
```

This would make the link.. now when they click it, in samepage.php you would want to look for it:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
   //query the db and pull that image..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the query string or `get variables`.  You can access a get variable through php with `$_GET['name']`.  For example:
     http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=793636552
everything after the `?` is the query string.  The name of the variable is `id`, so to access it through your php you would use `$_GET['id']`.  You can build onto these this an `&` in between the variables. For example:
     http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=793636552&photo=12345
And here we have `$_GET['id']` and `$_GET['photo']`.

Answer (score 0):

variables can be pulled out of URL's very easily:

www.site.com/index.php?id=12345

we can access the number after id with $_GET['id']

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

outputs:

```
12345
```

so if you had a list of records (or images, in your case), you can link to them even easier:

```
$query = mysql_query(...);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
for ($num=0;$num<=$numrows;$num++) {
    $array = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    echo "<a href=\"./index.php?id=". $row['id'] ."\" />Image #". $row['id'] ."</a>";
}
```

that will display all of your records like so:

```
Image #1 (links to: http://www.site.com/index.php?id=1)
Image #2 (links to: http://www.site.com/index.php?id=2)
Image #3 (links to: http://www.site.com/index.php?id=3)
...
```